# Change input color after user enters X characters with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an input, where the user types a text. What I want to do is: 
After the user enters 10 characters, the next characters they type will be another color. Does anyone know how I can do?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" maxlength="255">

  <script>
    let input = document.querySelector("input");

    input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
      if(input.value.length > 10) {
        console.log(input.value.substring(10));
      }
    })
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is an example code, I want to get this text after the user type 10 characters and change their color.

Comment: What you are describing would not be possible with an `input`. Inputs can only be one color, you cannot apply different CSS to different parts of the same input. For this you'd have to use a [contenteditable div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) and then wrap the characters that exceed the 10th character in a `span` or something.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do this?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/qkd01vpf/

Answer (score 0):

Coloring part of the input element's text is not possible, as the only CSS selector for part of a string of characters is [`::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter). Like @APAD1's comment says, an [element with `contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) could be created that automatically wraps the next 10 characters in a `span` tag with custom styling set.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do this?